# How to create disk from snapshot in google cloud function - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been struggling to find a solution for this particular problem. I've gone through almost all the documentation of `gcloud/compute` `node` module which is used in `google cloud functions`.

Now my challenge is to create a new `disk` from an existing `snapshot` in `google cloud function`.

I have used below code to create a disk. As they haven't provided any example to create a `disk` from a `snapshot`. Following `cloud function` creates a new `disk` named `disk1` which is entirely fresh and new disk. I don't want that. I want to create a disk from an existing `snapshot` which has some data and setup in it.

```js
exports.tempFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
  const Compute = require(`@google-cloud/compute`);
  const compute = new Compute();
  const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-a');
  const disk = zone.disk('disk1');
  
  const config = {
   // ...
    //os:'ubuntu'
 };

  disk.create(config, function(err, disk, operation, apiResponse) {
    // `disk` is a Disk object.

    // `operation` is an Operation object that can be used to check the
    // status of the request.
    console.log(err);
    console.log(disk);
    console.log(operation);
    console.log(apiResponse);
    res.status(200).send("success");
  });
 
};
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

P.S. I also tried using cloud APIs. But as I want only to use the `cloud functions` and I am unable to figure out that how do I get access token for `gcloud` to use inside `cloud functions`

Answer (score 1):

The disk creation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Zone#createDisk) can be customized by setting the disk resource fields [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks) in the config object.
In this case, set the `sourceSnapshot` field in the config to the existing snapshot partial or full URL. The code should look like this:

```js
exports.tempFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
  const Compute = require(`@google-cloud/compute`);
  const compute = new Compute();
  const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-a');
  const disk = zone.disk('disk1');
  
  const config = {
    sourceSnapshot: "projects/{YOUR-PROJECT}/global/snapshots/{YOUR_SNAPSHOT}"
  };

  disk.create(config, function(err, disk, operation, apiResponse) {
    // `disk` is a Disk object.

    // `operation` is an Operation object that can be used to check the
    // status of the request.
    console.log(err);
    console.log(disk);
    console.log(operation);
    console.log(apiResponse);
    res.status(200).send("success");
  });
 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I actually ended up using the APIs for achieving that as the  setting parameter in config object wasn't giving me any results. I did try using the `sourceSnapshot` param. But I was using the name of the snapshot rather than the path. I will try again with the path and let you know what happens.

Comment: Hello @DhrumilPatel , did you have an opportunity to test the `sourceSnapshot` solution with the path?